# とあるサイトの通信状況を調べて、JSONファイルの中身をPythonで取得しようとしたがうまくいかない

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

**やりたいこと**
下記のサイトのランキングをスクレイピングするために,
通信状況を調べjsonファイルからデータを取得しようと考えています。

https://www.spooncast.net/jp/ranking/topfan?date_type=daily

**実際のコード**
下記のコードを実行しましたがエラーになりました。

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url_rank = ('https://jp-api.spooncast.net/ranks/fan/?date_type=daily')

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(url_rank, headers=headers)
users = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r.json()['results']['author'])
users = users[['nickname', 'profile_url']]
```

**エラー内容**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0958c513ae04> in <module>
      4 headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      5 r = requests.get(url_rank, headers=headers)
----> 6 users = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r.json()['results']['author'])
      7 users = users[['nickname', 'profile_url']]
      8 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

strではなく整数かスライスでなければならないと書かれていますが、よくわかりません。
原因と解決策を教えていただけると嬉しいです。

また、このサイトはランキングが一つのリンクにまとまっておらず、4つに分かれています。
https://jp-api.spooncast.net/ranks/fan/?date_type=daily
https://jp-api.spooncast.net/ranks/fan/?cursor=cD0zMA%3D%3D&date_type=daily
https://jp-api.spooncast.net/ranks/fan/?cursor=cD02MA%3D%3D&date_type=daily
https://jp-api.spooncast.net/ranks/fan/?cursor=cD05MA%3D%3D&date_type=daily

開発者ツールについて使い慣れていないからかもしれませんが、これらの情報を一つに取得する方法はないのでしょうか？
それとも取得したデータを結合するとかしないとだめでしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> strではなく整数かスライスでなければならないと書かれていますが、よくわかりません。原因と解決策を教えていただけると嬉しいです。

エラーメッセージ `list indices must be ...` にある通り、`r.json()['results']` は辞書(dict)のリストになっています。なので、list comprehension か map で中身の dict を取り出す必要があります。具体的には以下の様にします。

```py
  users = pd.DataFrame.from_records(i['author'] for i in r.json()['results'])
```

> また、このサイトはランキングが一つのリンクにまとまっておらず、4つに分かれています。
>
> 開発者ツールについて使い慣れていないからかもしれませんが、これらの情報を一つに取得する方法はないのでしょうか？
> それとも取得したデータを結合するとかしないとだめでしょうか？

JSON データに `next` というタグが存在します。ここに次のランキングデータへの URL が格納されています。なので、この URL を辿って行きます。最後の JSON データの `next` タグには空文字列(`""`)が入っているので、これを繰り返し処理の終了条件とします(単方向のリンクリストを辿る処理と同じです)。

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url_rank = 'https://jp-api.spooncast.net/ranks/fan/?date_type=daily'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

users = []
while url_rank:
  json_data = requests.get(url_rank, headers=headers).json()
  data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(i['author'] for i in json_data['results'])
  users.append(data[['nickname', 'profile_url']])
  url_rank = json_data['next']

users = pd.concat(users).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**実行結果**

`print(users.to_markdown(index=False))`

| nickname | profile_url |
| --- | --- |
| lin3529 | https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJx6o-PjTqmgXSo6Mo8btONK14fbJLuXP_Jyjbjw=s96-c |
| 朧狼/☙♅❧廻煉豹月 | http://jp-cdn.spooncast.net/profiles/Q/qzoDbQwizpoPv0/8d4299f8-a4bb-4d5d-b094-42388a7699fc.jpg |
| ྖᴷ❥⃝果奈 | http://jp-cdn.spooncast.net/profiles/5/lN8oW5VsDZbrl0/eca7cf6a-f98c-4ecb-a464-b4d1bd3a613b.jpg |
| ✼̥.*ᶜここ | http://jp-cdn.spooncast.net/profiles/O/GQXJOObin2dV0l/d825680d-4c2a-4faa-b1e5-69a9a4903158.jpg |
| 華-ｼﾛ- | http://jp-cdn.spooncast.net/profiles/E/EM8mpE0tnv9vmN/556d4da5-c43c-443b-a7e5-3f74ed9b2bb1.jpg |
| ... | ... |
| ⚛︎*.⋆なる・J | http://jp-cdn.spooncast.net/profiles/X/No94RXbfORa3O0/974a2d90-7380-458e-bebf-d65310d9da0c.jpg |
| しゅん | http://jp-cdn.spooncast.net/profiles/0/EM8Nx0lFnEpjjj/e25449d8-0672-4163-bf19-a535e2dc0f4c.jpg |
| ちょんまる.㌨ | http://jp-cdn.spooncast.net/profiles/j/XL5BpjGFdkBbRK/aed5d327-5c69-4195-9082-fe960b105b43.jpg |
| ⁷⁴なじ | http://jp-cdn.spooncast.net/profiles/L/JaoG6LDue3ML6O/c021388f-4860-4f4c-aaca-73b7ba1d86e6.jpg |
| 黎斗 | http://jp-cdn.spooncast.net/profiles/G/PMAGnGjub5bKjE/afd151dc-15d3-443a-ba6d-a385125d8edc.jpg |